# How to change UIBarButtonItem's title color when placed in a UIToolbar?

Tags: ios

I've tried setting the title text attributes. The Button is set by using an icon and then setting the title property. The icon is properly tinted. The title remains 'untinted'

Screenshot attached.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If tintColor does not affect the text color, the only solution I know of is to essentially create a composite image of the icon and text, then use that as your button image:

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(someSize, NO, 0);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// draw the image
// Use UIKit NSString additions to draw the text

UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Hmmm well, at least I won't have to individually modify each toolbar icon to add the text in photoshop! I'll give this a shot.

Answer (score 0):

David's suggestion works. Here is sample code:

```
 + (UIImage *) image:(NSString *) imageName withTitle:(NSString *)title {

     UIFont *titleFont = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:10];
     CGSize textSize = [title sizeWithFont:titleFont];

     CGFloat width = MAX(35, textSize.width);
     UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(width, 35), NO, 0);
     CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

     UIImage *toolbarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
     CGContextSaveGState(context);  {
         CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0, 35);
         CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);
         CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake((width - toolbarImage.size.width) / 2, 14, toolbarImage.size.width, toolbarImage.size.height), toolbarImage.CGImage);
     }
     CGContextRestoreGState(context);

     [title drawInRect:CGRectMake((width - textSize.width) / 2, 22, textSize.width, textSize.height) withFont:titleFont];

     UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
     UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return image;
```

}

Tweak some of the frame parameters to fit your images.